# Flask jsonify - how to send string back?

Tags: python, json, utf-8, flask

I'm building API that sends result back in string format.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def converter():
    content = request.json
    # translate() - english to hindi
    converted = translate(content)
    print converted
    #prints string normally
    return jsonify({"result":converted})
```

When try `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor."}' http://localhost:5000/` it sends me back

```
{
  "result": "\u041b\u043e\u0440\u044d\u043c \u0438\u043f\u0441\u04af\u043c \u0434\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0440 \u0441\u0438\u0442 \u0430\u043c\u044d\u0442, c\u043e\u043d\u0441\u044dc\u0442\u044d\u0442\u04af\u044d\u0440 \u0430\u0434\u0438\u043f\u0438\u0441c\u0438\u043d\u0433 \u044d\u043b\u0438\u0442. \u0410\u044d\u043d\u044d\u0430\u043d c\u043e\u043c\u043c\u043e\u0434\u043e \u043b\u0438\u0433\u04af\u043b\u0430 \u044d\u0433\u044d\u0442 \u0434\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0440."
}
```

How can I send back the strings instead of json object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't wrap the result inside the `jsonify` call, and simply `return converted`:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def converter():
    content = request.json
    converted = translate(content)
    return converted
```

Answer (score 1):

I think jsonify uses ASCII by default. There is a configuration option:

```
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False
```

that will set the default to unicode.